# How to automate taking screenshots of a web page from the local nginx webserver... headless, with no x server or web browser

Tags: nginx, automation, webpage-screenshot, timelapse

I need to automate taking full-page screen shots at specific intervals of a web page that is being generated from a web server running on a Raspberry Pi SBC.  The Pi is running the latest Bullseye Lite OS (no X server or browser installed), and the software serving the website is called Mycodo, and it is using nginx as it's web server.
What I need to do is basically generate a time-lapse video of this web page.  The page is a dashboard of gauges and graphs logging data from an automated climate-control system.
I do not want to have to use a web browser running on a separate machine to take the screenshots, I need to be able to take these screenshots from the local machine the web server is running on (the Raspberry Pi running Mycodo and the nginx web server). Then store those screenshots to a specified folder on the Pi.  I also need these images to be in 1920x1080 resolution and date-time-stamped in the file name so they are in chronological order so they can be easily compiled into video using a video-editing app such as KDENLive.

My problem is that I am not a programmer, and I have not been able to find any apps or Linux packages that will allow me to do this. I basically don't even know where to start to accomplish this in a Linux environment.

Any suggestions, scripts, apps, tools, would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

There were a couple of older linux apps or packages that could do this, but I have not been able to get them to work at all.